# Changing default TextColor in Xamarin.Forms Listview on Android

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, android-styles

I am trying to change the default `TextColor` in a Xamarin.Forms ListView on Andoid.

The ListView is quite simple:

```
List<string> cities = new List<string> { "Berlin", "Bonn", "Braunschweig", "Bremen" };
ListView listView = new ListView();
listView.ItemsSource = cities;
Content = listView;
```

On the device it looks like this:

[image]

What I wnat to have, is that the `TextColor` will be black.
As far as I understand [Xamarin Forms CustomRenderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.ControlGallery.Android/CustomRenderers.cs)  there will be a `Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1` generated for each item.

[SimpleListItem1](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml) uses the following textAppearance:

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
```

`textAppearanceListItemSmall` uses the Attribute `textAppearanceMedium` for rendering, as you can see [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/themes.xml).

So I have added the colors and the theme to the resouces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
  <color name="Black">#000000</color>
</resources>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:textAppearanceMedium">@style/MyDefaultTextAppearanceM</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyDefaultTextAppearanceM" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/Black</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

I have also added the Theme to the Attribute for my Activity (`Theme = "@style/MyTheme`)
The Theme is basically working. With `<item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/Blue4</item>` I can change the HighlightColor.

So how can I get the text color in ListView black? What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

Try to add this before you set the Content:

```
var template = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));
template.SetValue(TextCell.TextColorProperty, Color.Black);
listView.ItemTemplate = template;
```

Comment: You also have to add template.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "."); then it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the conversation, but maybe this will others down the road.

Xaml based solution, very simple - Just set the TextColor on the ImageCell. Like so:

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ListView x:Name="listView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                SeparatorVisibility="None">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ImageCell TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Title}"
                            ImageSource="{Binding IconSource}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyTextCell), typeof(MyTextCellRenderer))]
namespace MyNamespace.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class MyTextCellRenderer : TextCellRenderer
    {
        protected override Android.Views.View GetCellCore(Cell item, Android.Views.View convertView, ViewGroup parent, Context context)
        {
            Android.Views.View result =  base.GetCellCore(item, convertView, parent, context);

            (result as BaseCellView).SetDefaultMainTextColor(Color.Black);

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```